# How to Enable AWS RDS Audit logs, & Associate Option group to RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, devops, audit-logging

Can anyone please help me out with enabling Audit logs for Aurora Mysql(5.7.12) RDS instance, only audit logs not able to capture other 3 types of logs were able to see.

I have created custom option group for MariaDBAudit plugin, but i couldnt find any option to add this OptionGroup to DB Instance.

Answer (score 0):

Open the **Amazon RDS console.**

Choose Databases from the navigation pane.

Select the DB instance that you want to use to export log data to CloudWatch.

Choose **Modify**.

From the Log exports section, select the **Audit log**.

Choose Continue.

Review the Summary of modifications, and choose Modify instance.

**EDIT:**
Enable following in option group to see logs in cloudwatch.

```
SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATIONS
```

and

```
SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATE_SIZE
```

Comment: Its not working , As i said other 3 types of  logs working means I have already did the same right ?, Could you please point me to some other